# Python plot real time data for last 100 points

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, real-time

I have a large time series pandas dataframe that contains minute data for the past few years:

```
df = ['timestamp', 'A', 'B']
```

I'd like to make a real time plot only for the last 100 data points, as I don't want to compute over the entire set. The data is updated every minute from an sql database. I can plot it once fine, but I'm having difficulties using the while true statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be significantly easier to help if you show us what you have.

Comment: No one here can estimate what the problem of you "having difficulties using the while true statement" actually is. If you have a problem with an actual code, provide a [mcve] of it. If you have a conceptual question, phrase it such that it is understandable and add some pseudocode to make it clear.

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you needed?

```
import time
while True:
    # Plot the last 100 data points
    time.sleep(60)
```